# Angular Spinner Usage Without using timeout

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with angular spinner here, i have a update button inthat i'm using spin and loading needs to be stopped after saving the data in to database without using any timeout function i need stop that loading

```
  function assignLectureToSubject(subject) {
            subject.$update();
        }
```

above code is the function for update button

Comment: Where is your call to the database ? What is `$update()` ?

Comment: You can use ```ng-class``` to toggle a class which animates the spinner; something like ```<div ng-class="{'loading': updating}"></div>``` where ```loading``` is the class containing animation and ```updating``` is the scope variable which you need to set before/after your server call.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a genric solution, You can use [`interceptors`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors), Here is an example. Perform your operation for `ShowWaitIndicator` and  `HideWaitIndicator` functions

```
app.factory('waitingInterceptor', ['$q', '$rootScope',
    function ($q, $rootScope) {
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                ShowWaitIndicator();
                return config || $q.when(config);
            },
            requestError: function(request){
                HideWaitIndicator();
                return $q.reject(request);
            },
            response: function (response) {
                HideWaitIndicator();
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },
            responseError: function (response) {
                HideWaitIndicator();
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
}]);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('waitingInterceptor');    
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag. lets call it isUpdating

```
$scope.isUpdating = false;

function update(){
  $scope.isUpdating = true;
  $http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.isUpdating = false;
 }, function errorCallback(response) {
    $scope.isUpdating = false;
  });
}
```

And in the HTML,

```
<your-spinner ng-show='isUpdating'>
```

Initially, spinner is hidden. When update is called, the spinner starts showing on the page. And when the event completes, the callback sets the flag to false, thereby hiding it again.